# image get upload successfully in folder. it is not displayed immediately when that page renders

Tags: node.js, angularjs, multer

when I am uploading a new image its not displaying and giving 404 error. all previous upload image is displaying. it is not displaying immediately. when I off server then restart it display that.

I am using angular as frontend and node express setup at backend using multer for uploading images and mongodb as db

I have checked all paths its all good

I error its showing image as 404 not found and type image is text/html
[image]

```
 <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col sm" *ngFor="let post of usersdata.post">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 310px">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{'../../../assets/img/Uploads/UserPosts/'+post.postUrl}}"  height="250"alt="Card image">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="ui  avatar image" src="{{'../../../assets/img/Uploads/Profile image/'+usersdata.img}}">
                                <span class="card-title"> <b>{{usersdata.name}}</b> </span>
                            <br><br><p class="card-text">{{post.caption}}</p>
                              <hr/>

                              <div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
                                <div (click)="toggle()" [ngClass]="buttn">
                                    <i class="far fa-heart"></i> Like
                                </div> 
                                <a class="ui basic red left pointing label">
                                  {{like}}
                                </a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
                                <div (click)="toggle2()" [ngClass]="buttn2">
                                    <i class="fas fa-heart-broken"></i> DisLike 
                                </div>
                                <a class="ui basic left pointing black label">
                                    {{dislike}}
                                  </a>
                              </div><br><br>
                              <button class="ui right floated basic black button"> <i class="far fa-comment fa-2x "></i></button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Can't really help you out with just some description and a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue while creating your URL for rendering the Image because the error you have is 404 which means the resource you are looking for with the HTTP request is not present. you can check the URL of your other images which are getting rendered and match with the failed one(with necessary changes).

Comment: i have loop moving in one container to get names of image so every image has same path . its not displaying when just upload image. it is not loading in sources or website